# ADFS 3.0 relying party URL redirect

Tags: redirect, single-sign-on, adfs

We have two relying party endpoints that customers can configure in ADFS 3.0 for SAML 2.0 SSO.

1. https://blah/saml2/mylink
2. https://blah/saml2/mylink?redirect=differentpage

When they click on both connections, they get taken to the "mylink" page. Is there something in the ADFS relying party field that cannot handle the "?redirect" syntax, so that it defaults to the "mylink" page?

Answer (score 1):

In short, SAML 2.0 specification doesn't support redirect url like that. IdP (ADFS in this case) always returns the consumer endpoint which is /mylink in your case. A common trick is to use relaystate. You can set the relaystate attribute to the url you want to return after login, e.g. /mylink?redirect=differentpage. Please note that you will need to write code to do that redirection yourself after your application receives response from ADFS and finishes processing it.

Comment: Thanks - I will ask my engineers. Is the relaystate attribute something the customer configures in ADFS?

Comment: It is a string your SP sends to ADFS with the AuthnRequest and ADFS will return the exact string back to your SP with its Response.